# How can I invoke keyboard accelerators programmatically in WinUI UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui, winui-3

Is there a way to invoke default Windows shortcuts like <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> programmatically in [WinUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_UI_Library) [UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform)?

Some shortcuts, like <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, don't have any API calls as far as I know. Hence, I want to invoke them by triggering them programmatically. Is there a solution?

As suggested by @Zer0, I used *keyboard input injection*. It is working. But, after injection, the physical keyboard starts to malfunction. The keys which I press on the keyboard map to different keys and Windows starts opening *random applications*. This issue persists for 10 seconds even after closing my application. After 10 seconds, this issue disappears. Why is it behaving so?

By the way, this is my code:

```
var V = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo();
V.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.None;
V.VirtualKey = (ushort)VirtualKey.V;
var Win = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo();
Win.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.None;
Win.VirtualKey = (ushort)VirtualKey.LeftWindows;
injector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { Win,V });
```

Comment: [Input Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/input-injection)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. But I am facing an issue with InputInjection. I have edited my question. Can you provide a solution ?

Comment: I don't see an edit.  Please post the code and what happens (why it doesn't work) when you run it.

Comment: Can you see the edited question now ?

Comment: "The physical keyboard starts to malfunction"?  Huh, you managed to break hardware with that code?  Can you post an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I have edited the question and have elaborated some more on the Issue. Hope you can understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to release the *Windows* key after you inject the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> successfully.

You could try this:

```
InputInjector inputInjector = InputInjector.TryCreate();

InjectedInputKeyboardInfo infoV = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo();
infoV.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.None;
infoV.VirtualKey = (ushort)VirtualKey.V;

// Windows key is an extended key.
InjectedInputKeyboardInfo infoW = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo();
infoW.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.ExtendedKey;
infoW.VirtualKey = (ushort)VirtualKey.LeftWindows;

inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { infoW, infoV });

// Release the key
infoW.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.KeyUp;
infoW.VirtualKey = (ushort)VirtualKey.LeftWindows;

inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { infoW });
```

Comment: Can you also share the link where I can find which keys are extended keys ?

Comment: @Kris An extended key is a function key or a key on the numeric keypad.